# What are the French equivalents of "blow away the cobwebs"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

We were having a conversation after a concert, and I said:

> C’est bon de sortir de temps à autre pour se divertir un peu, d'autant plus que j'ai passé mes dernières journées à compulser de vieux documents poussiéreux, enfermé dans mon bureau. (...) Il faut faire avec, ça fait partie du boulot, mais quand même. Écouter cette agréable mélodie... c’est **comme un vent frais qui chasse les toiles d’araignées** !

Here I was talking about how going to a concert on holiday makes for a nice diversion after spending an entire week cooped up in an office. Essentially, I wanted to express the idea of:

- *Listening to this beautiful music... Ahh, it really **blows away the cobwebs**!*

The expression "*blow away the cobwebs*" comes in handy when you want to say:

- *Doing some light exercise or going for a little walk etc helps you feel **physically** more energetic as well as **mentally** more alert.*

As I didn't know a commonly used phrase for this, I sort of resorted to *brute force* and said the phrasing above that came to mind right there and then.

Alternatively, I might have said: "***Ça chasse les toiles d’araignées***", or straying from the literal wording: "***Ça change les idées***, **ça fait du bien**".

I'm not sure if the literal interpretation "*chasser les toiles d’araignées*" works in French, to begin with. How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in French?

Comment: Maybe something based on "décrasser", to keep the cleaning theme? Not very poetic though.

Answer (score 6):

En français on chasse les toiles d'araignées essentiellement au sens propre, ou pour dire qu'on donne un donne un coup de jeune, qu'on dépoussière (au sens métaphorique) quelque chose de vieillot.

« Changer les idées » est surtout valable pour l'influence sur le moral, on sous entend en général une amélioration du moral. Whereas when something blows the cobwebs away you feel mentally better of course, but physically as well, you feel less tired.

Pour le contexte que tu donnes on peut envisager (entre autres) les verbes *ravigoter* et *revigorer*. Les deux signifient « redonner de la force/de la vigueur ».

Bien que **ravigoter** se dise plus souvent quand la cause de l’amélioration est une nourriture (ou une boisson) :

- J'avais bien besoin de ce repas, merci. Il m'a ravigoté. Je vais pouvoir gravir des montagnes.

on l'emploie aussi quand la cause est autre :

> Deux journées à Marseille avec Sartre me ravigotèrent (Simone de Beauvoir, *La force de l'âge*).

**Revigorer** peut aussi s'appliquer quelle que soit la cause du changement.

> Son vin chaud qui revigorerait un mort ! (Blaise Cendrars, *Bourlinguer*)

> Comme nous avions toutes deux de la santé et de l'appétit, nos conversations désabusées, loin de me déprimer, me revigoraient. (Simone de Beauvoir, *Mémoires d'une jeune fille rangée*).

Tu pourrais dire :

- Cette musique est revigorante.
- Cette promenade m'a ravigoté.

Not as graphic as blowing the cobwebs away of course.

Si on cherche une expression un peu imagée en français il y a « redonner du pep », qui est un emprunt à l'anglais *pep someone up*).

- Cette promenade m'a redonné du pep.

Dans l'esprit imagé on peut aussi dire « avoir la frite », donc :

- Cette promenade m'a redonné la frite.

qui est un dérivé de l'expression originale « [avoir la patate](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-la-frite-la-patate.php) » qui est je crois moins employée de nos jour.

Si on n'aime pas les tubercules et qu'on préfère les fruits « [avoir la pêche](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/avoir-la-peche/) » est une expression aussi relativement fréquente.

> Parce que la musique guérit tous les maux et permet d’apaiser les cœurs, on vous a concocté une playlist qui redonne la pêche. ([Cosmopolitan](https://www.cosmopolitan.fr/,la-playlist-qui-donne-la-peche,1931955.asp)

Comment: It might be a strange evolution but I've always seen the plural form "donner du peps", which seems to be where this expression is heading nowadays (6 million google result versus 2.6 millions)

Comment: @PierreArlaud Les deux se disent même si le TLF ne donne que pep. Et le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pep#fr), parle de variante, ainsi que le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @PierreArlaud, on dit plus 'donner du peps', je n'ai jamais entendu la version au singulier ...

Comment: @ASTEFANI Ce n'est pas parce que tu ne l'as jamais entendu que ça n'existe pas. Les deux se disent et encore aujourd'hui.  On a souvent tendance à n'entendre que ce qui est dit dans son cercle immédiat. Si tu ne l'as jamais entendu, cherche des exemple par écrit, ils sont nombreux. Et il me semble qu'au Québec on dit plus souvent *pep* que *peps* - mais à confirmer par un Québecois.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would say something along the line of *se vider la tête*, *se vider l'esprit*.

> - Écouter cette agréable mélodie... tu te vides la tête et t'oublies les soucis !

As a side note, I'm not sure wind will do much against cobwebs, what you want is a good broomstick.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I guess the phrasing "*c’est comme un **vent** frais*" came to mind,  influenced by a similar expression "*un second **souffle***".

Answer (score 2):

On peut aussi dire "*ça remet les idées en place*"

Answer (score 1):

*Chasser les toiles d'araignée* Fonctionne effectivement bien en français quand il s'agit de faire passer l'idée de [rajeunissement, de renouveau] de quelque chose plus que [d'aération, divertissement, break] d'une personne.

Ainsi pour ce qui est d'un exercice physique oxygénant, et, par surcroît précédé d'une onomatopée style PFFF! ou HaH! je crois que c'est "ça *fait du bien!*" qui viendra spontanément.

Pour ce qui est du domaine des idées, je sais qu'Isabelle Rigaux traduit *Rafraichir les idées* par *to blow away the cobwebs* mais :

pour ce qui est du bien fait par un divertissement d'une tâche laborieuse, je préférerais sans doute effectivement le *changer les idées*,

Quant à se divertir d'une charge plus morale, je dirais plutôt : *chasser les idées noires*

---

<sup>Enfin, pour ce qui est de *blow the cobwebs*... grace à la musique... on m'en voudrait certainement de ne pas rappeler la réplique dite *culte* de Francis Blanche se mettant au piano dans *"les barbouzes*" : "*Boris va chasser les miasmes*" ;-)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is a shift in point of view that is unacceptable in "C’est bon de sortir de temps à autre pour se divertir un peu, d'autant plus que j'ai passé mes dernières journées à compulser de vieux documents poussiéreux, enfermé dans mon bureau. (...)". "C’est bon de sortir de temps à autre" is a general statement made to characterise something true for every one, then it is particularised through a personal point of view. Therefore an adjustment is necessary: either "Ça m'a fait du bien… d'autant plus que j'ai…" or "C'est bon de sortir… d'autant plus que vous venez de passer un moment à une tâche ingrate."; the first option is the one in this paragraph.

That being said, there seems to be no such reference to "toile d'araignée" in the French language; there is apparently no set expression and the analogies are in a domain that sticks to the most evident: filter like appearance, delicate structure of the web ([TFLi, **B 2**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/araign%C3%A9e)). That makes it a quasi-impossibility to use the concept, except in a longer parabola, where the meaning is not figurative but analogic, as for instance in the following;

- Écouter cette agréable mélodie... c’est comme un vent frais, un nettoyage de printemps qui élimine les toiles d’araignées !

To keep to a factual vein one could translate as in the sentence below;

- ... c’est comme un vent frais, ça ranime !

  "Ça change les idées, ça fait du bien" is just as good a means to render the expression " brush away/clear away/dust away/ blow away the cobwebs".

Comment: You are misinterpreting the structure of the 1st sentence. The "*d'autant plus que*" subordinate clause could just as well be seen as a separate sentence or an independent clause added as an afterthought: "*C’est bon de sortir de temps à autre pour se divertir un peu. D'autant plus que j'ai passé ..." or "C’est bon de sortir de temps à autre pour se divertir un peu -- d'autant plus que j'ai passé ...*" As such, the logical connection/continuity of "*on/je*" does not matter here, especially in an informal, spontaneous conversation like this. Anyway, this point is not related to the question.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I do not believe that; the conjunction is called in French "correlative" and that means that a connection has been established with the idea formulated in the main clause; the situation represented is being asserted as being even more justified because of the situation explained in the subordinate. To use the locution "dautant que" in another way is to misuse it; if you don't want this connection you have to use something else and preserve the integrity of "d'autant plus que". (TLFi: 1. [Suivi du **corrélatif que**] D'autant plus + adj. (...) que ).