# Comment traduire « full of beans » : adjectif simple, syntagme ou locution ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique

En anglais on a l'« adjectif idiomatique » *full of beans*, signifiant entre autres « energetic and enthusiastic » ([Wiktionnaire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_of_beans#Adjective)) ou « [full](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/full#Anglais) of energy and life » ([Merriam Learners](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/full%20of%20beans)) :

> Jem was among them, pink-cheeked and *full of beans* after his long
>   sleep. ([tFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/full+of+beans))

Dans un tel cas, avec un registre plutôt informel, préférerait-on traduire avec un seul adjectif ou avec un syntagme ou avec une locution ou expression idiomatique équivalente (lequel ou laquelle ?) et pourquoi ; comment dans ce dernier cas l'articulerait-on en épithète coordonnée comme dans l'exemple (par ex. *...était de la partie, le teint rose et [...] après son long sommeil*) ?

Comment: ;-) Tu crois que ça ne va pas [doublonner](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/what-are-the-french-equivalents-of-blow-away-the-cobwebs) ?

Comment: @Laure Ça m'étonnerait, ça ne m'est que très peu arrivé sur des centaines de questions. On pourrait peut-être dire qu'être _full of beans_ peut résulter dans certains cas du fait d'avoir _blowé les cobwebs_...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En ce qui concerne les expressions, la première qui me vient à l'esprit c'est « péter le feu ».

- il était de la partie, le teint rose et **pétant le feu** après son long sommeil.

On peut aussi « péter la forme ».

Ensuite on peut reprendre d'autres expressions plus culinaires :

> 4 moyens pour augmenter votre métabolisme d’une façon naturelle et avoir une **patate d’enfer** tout en gardant la banane ([Manger vivant](https://www.mangervivant.fr/augmenter-son-metabolisme/)).

[La patate ou la frite](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-la-frite-la-patate.php)....

- il était de la partie, le teint rose et avec **frite d'enfer**  après son long sommeil.

Mais je préfère la pêche et ça va si bien avec le teint rose !

- il était de la partie, le teint rose avec **une pêche d'enfer**  après son long sommeil.

Avec la patate, la frite et la pêche on peut aussi introduire une comparaison :

- il était de la partie, le teint rose et **la patate/la frite/la pêche retrouvée** après son long sommeil.

Et même si l'expression est peut-être plus employée pour parler de choses que de personnes, on peut aussi être **plein de pep** :

> Ce fut une très belle journée ou [*sic*] tout le monde présent était plein de pep et d'enthousiasme. ([Blog québécois](http://www.amicaledesretraitesbnc.ca/fr/Reportages-activites-et-loisirs/Montreal---Monteregie/))

Comment: Penses-tu que _pétant le feu_ avec le participe présent c'est moins usuel ou différemment senti qu'avec le verbe conjugué ?

Comment: @personne Je pense que c'est plus facilement employé sous la forme « je pète le feu ». Mais pour l'intégrer dans la phrase que tu donnes le participe présent me semblait la meilleure formule.