# Conveying the idea of "alive and kicking"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

What are some colloquial ways to express in French "[alive and kicking](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/alive+and+kicking)" (meaning alive and healthy) as in the following examples

> - A: "How are you doing after your surgery?"
> - B: "I'm alive and kicking!"
>
> She ran a marathon late in life, just to prove she was still alive and kicking.
>
> After years of slow earnings, the industry is now alive and kicking.

I am thinking about *plein de vie*, *(être) bien vivant*. Other ways?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/38362/358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very common phrase: *être en plein forme*

> Comment ça va depuis ton opération ?
>
> Je suis en pleine forme.

Some more colloquial phrases:

1. *péter la forme*
2. *avoir la pêche/la frite/la patate*

Comment: Super ! Merci ! péter la forme (et non pêter, n'est-ce pas ?) et péter le cable sont-elles des expressions familiales ?

Comment: J'ai corrigé *péter*, merci ! *Péter la forme* et *péter un câble* (pas *le* câble) sont plus *familières* que *familiales* (on les utilisera avec ses enfants, sa famille, amis, collègues proches, etc).

Comment: J'ai ajouté aussi *avoir la patate*.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Of course "péter la forme" as a translation of "alive and kicking" is not so bad, but it misses a key point of that English expression, related to the "kicking" which means almost literally that, nonetheless you are alive, but you are also able to kick a ball as a player, say a basketball player.

An other important point in that expression is that it is twofold: first you are alive, but, much better, you are kicking. I would suggest

-- Comment allez-vous ?

-- Ecoutez, je suis en vie et performant.

Comment: Kicking the ball is a rather bad idea if you play basketball...

Answer (score 1):

For a person (especially an old one), you can say "bon pied, bon œil".