# "Comment ça pète ?" : reconnue ?

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, créole

J'ai entendu une créole française saluer son interlocuteur au téléphone comme suit :"

> Comment ça pète ?

Elle m'a dit que la tournure signifie "comment ça va ?" et elle est utilisée à la Réunion. Je crois qu'elle est reliée à l'expression '[péter la forme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39549/conveying-the-idea-of-alive-and-kicking/39550#39550)'.

La tournure est-elle reconnue en France métropolitaine ?

Comment: Correction: Vive la Réunion! alors. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connue, je ne crois pas mais elle serait probablement comprise dans un contexte tel que celui de la question. Si on me dit: ***Bonjour, comment ça pète ?*** je me doute bien que mon interlocuteur n'évoque pas des flatulences...

Dans la phrase exclamative ***Comment ça pète !*** voire ***Comment que ça pète !*** l'expression se rencontre en français relâché mais sert à signifier son admiration ou son étonnement devant quelque chose qui fait du bruit ou qui a de l'effet (instrument de musique, moto, coups de feu, bijou, etc.)

On peut aussi, pourquoi pas, tenter le rapprochement entre ***Comment ça pète ?*** et l'expression culte inventée par Jean Dujardin dans Brice de Nice, ***[Salut, ça farte ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tvk259o52o0)*** ;-) Bien, sûr, il s'agit ici du verbe « farter » , enduire de « fart » (cire) un surf ou des skis.